# Roots of polynomials in Z/pZ

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, quotient-spaces

Let $p$ be a prime and $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z[x] $ be the set of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb Z /p\mathbb Z $ What can you say about the roots of the polynomial $x^{p-1} -[1] \in \mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z$.

I know that if $[a] \in \mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z$ then the root of a polynomial say $g \ \in \mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z$ is: $g([a]) = [0]. $

Can anyone provide some guidance am I suppose to use fermat's little theorem to deduce something?

Comment: Hint. What if you apply Fermat's Little Theorem to the polynomial you are asking about?  Use the second line of your question.

Comment: Start with $1^n = 1$ and use the induction $(a+1)^p = a+1\operatorname{mod}(p)$ as induction on $a$: $(1+1)^p = 1+1  \operatorname{mod}(p)$ to arrive at $a^p=a\operatorname{mod}(p) \forall  a$